# VB or Kofax Script format string

Tags: javascript, c#, vb.net, vbscript

### When I have more than one "xxx.xxx.xx" or "xxx,xxx,xx" how i can replace all to result in this format (1000,12)? I just need an exemple the language is not important.

Input test case:

1000 .12

1,000.12

1.000.12

1,000,12

1000,,12

### 1000.12

Output:
1000,12

Comment: This question has no evidence of what you have tried, you have tagged it with multiple language tags, what are you using? At the very least you should provide a [mcve]. Please go away read [ask] and come back and edit your question. At the moment it is "too broad" for [so].

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this

```
            string[] inputs = { "1000.12", "1,000.12", "1.000.12", "1,000,12", "1000,,12", "1000.12" };
            for (int i = 0; i < inputs.Count(); i++)
            {
                inputs[i] = inputs[i].Replace(".", "");
                inputs[i] = inputs[i].Replace(",", "");

                string output = inputs[i].Substring(0, inputs[i].Length - 2) + "," + inputs[i].Substring(inputs[i].Length - 1);
                Console.WriteLine(output);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Wow, try this...no explanation no reference to what language the code sample is written in. To be perfectly honest the question is "too broad" so you shouldn't even be answering it in a first place. If you are going to answer it though at least try and make the answer more readable and useful then the question is.

Comment: Lankymart : The language wasn't important, just the algorithm.

Comment: If the *"language wasn't important"* it doesn't belong on [so] and is out of the scope for the site, would be better to suited to one of the other sites.